# RenderPrint not updating on observeEvent

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

When clicking on action button, I can see the google sheet downloading and date printed in console but the filetime in renderPrint is not updating?

```
library(httr)
set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )
library(googlesheets)
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      #One action button to download data from google spreadsheet
      actionButton("refreshbutton", label = "Refresh"),
      #two textoutput to show date of downloaded file
      textOutput("refreshdate")

      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

observeEvent(input$refreshbutton, {
  #On click download data from google spreadsheet
  pulldata <- gs_key("19bPhlp7MjDZFNJcDUmHGJDxkh2h2U5j05S0c18HfBgE") %>% 
    gs_read_csv(ws="vs working", col_names=TRUE)
  #Write data in csv
  write.csv(pulldata, file = "attrition.csv")
  data <- read.csv(file="attrition.csv", header = TRUE)
  #capture modified time from csv
  filetime <- file.mtime("attrition.csv")
  print(filetime)
  #inform on completion after refresh
})

#print filetime in refreshdate1
output$refreshdate <- renderPrint({ 
  filetime # <- This is not updating???
})
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Along with the above code, when Google spreadsheet is downloading, I assume the site should go to grey mode indicating refresh - this also is not happening? I mean it should show somehow that new data is in process till complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is not working is because the scope of the `filetime` variable is within the `observeEvent`. You cannot assign a variable outside its scope using `observeEvent`, instead use `eventReactive`.

Just checked it, `gs_key` is throwing an error for me even in R console, otherwise this is the solution you were looking for regarding reactivity.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$refreshbutton, {
    #On click download data from google spreadsheet
    pulldata <- gs_key("19bPhlp7MjDZFNJcDUmHGJDxkh2h2U5j05S0c18HfBgE") %>%
      gs_read_csv(ws="vs working", col_names=TRUE)
    #Write data in csv
    write.csv(pulldata, file = "attrition.csv")
    #read.csv(file="attrition.csv", header = TRUE)
  })

  filetime <- eventReactive(input$refreshbutton, {
    file.mtime("attrition.csv")
  })

  #print filetime in refreshdate1
  output$refreshdate <- renderPrint({ 
    filetime()
  })
}
```

Error message:

> ```
> Expected content-type:
> application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8
> Actual content-type:
> text/html; charset=UTF-8
> ```

Comment: But the output is not just a date, it has other things such as Download.... etc with it? How can I split this to one?

Comment: You're right, sorry. I didn't care about anything but the refreshdate.

Comment: Perfect, Can I print filetime (lastest csv time) before clicking the button; as in when it loads.

Comment: You can, just replace `output$refreshdate` with this code: (if action button hasn't been clicked get filetime)

`output$refreshdate <- renderPrint({ 
    if(input$refreshbutton == 0) file.mtime("attrition.csv")
    else filetime()
  })`